# Defining common methods for React functional component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I have created a 4 page application using typescript and hooks. There are few methods within each file which is common. Is there any way so that same methods can be extended in all file. Something like abstract in typescript without changing my component to class from functional?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very easily. Create js File `Message.js` and write the below function

```
export function getMessage() {
    return "Hello World";
}
```

import that function to your another js file where you want to call:

```
import {getMessage} from './Message'
```

Then call the `getMessage` function:

```
alert("This is the Message: " + getMessage());
```